$\sin(z)/z$ takes on every complex value
Define $f(0)=1$ and $f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)}{z}$ for $z \neq 0$. I would like to show that the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{C}$.
We know $f$ is entire since it is the quotient of two entire functions with a removal singularity at the origin. By Picard, $f$ misses at most one value $w$, and we can show that if it misses $w$, it misses $\overline{w}$ so $w$ must be real. Since $\sin(x)/x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ attains every value in $[0,1]$, $w<0$ or $w>1$. At this point, I would like to use Rouché theorem and the fact that $\sin(z)=w$ has a solution for every $w$, but not sure how.

Another way of doing this is to assume that $\sin z/z$ doesn't take value $c$ which means $\sin z-cz$ never vanishes so it is $e^{h(z)}$ but then by order considerations we get that $h(z)=az+b$ and then various limit considerations (eg taking $z=x\to +\infty$) give you a contradiction

Assume that $f$ does not take the value $c \in \Bbb C$. Surely $c \ne 0$. Then
$$
 g(z) = \sin(z) - cz
$$
does not take the value zero. For every $k \in \Bbb Z$ is
$$
 g(z - 2 \pi k) = \sin(z - 2\pi k) - c(z - 2 \pi k) = g(z) + 2\pi k c
$$
so that $g$ does not take any of the values $2 \pi k c$, $k \in \Bbb Z$. By Picard's theorem it follows that $g$ is constant, but that is not possible.
